# javascript and grep to replace a variable

Tags: javascript, regex, grep

I have some lists of numbers that I frequently have to change by hand a small sample is listed there in var str (#1 below) right now when this runs it gives (#2) as the output. What I want to happen is for var xyz to change every time it hits a new section and continue labeling them with the new var until it gets to the next section. (#3)
I hope my question is clear. (apparently it is not...)
I know I'm doing something very wrong and this might not be written in the best way in the first place. So any tips would be appreciated.

(19.32  spec03 20.56    2 20.84 3   39.32   spec04 30.56    2 30.84 3)

(19.32  spec03 20.56    spec06 20.84    spec06  39.32   spec04 30.56    spec06 30.84    spec06  )

(**19.32    spec03** 20.56  spec03 20.84    spec03  **39.32 spec04** 30.56  spec04 30.84    spec04) [the bolded values being the first instance of a new section]

```
var xyz = 'spec06';
var str = '19.32    spec03 20.56    2 20.84 3';
var patt1 = /([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\t)([0-9]+)/;
var patt2 = /([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\t)(spec[0-9]+)/;
function cleaner() {
for (i = 1; i <= 150; i++) {
    //xyz = str.replace(patt2, '$1') <-- this crashes the program...?
    str = str.replace(patt1, '$1' + xyz)

    }

}
```

[live version](http://jsfiddle.net/wyE2x/3/) note: you need some tab separated input for it to respond...

here is a sample of some input i would be using:
278.091182  spec35 279.300274   2 279.842670    3 280.204268    4 281.006563    5 281.503759    6 282.339954    7 282.532053    8 282.690252    9 283.300448    10 285.357034   11 285.718632   12 286.407927   e 287.809118 spec36 288.747012  2 288.927811    3 289.266809    4

Comment: I don; t think I can understand the question very well. Could you try rephrasing it and organizing it so that all thos numbers aren't burried inside the text?

Comment: Okay I could see how that could be a problem I added some spaces and a link to a live version on jsfiddle. I hope that helps make it clear what I'm going for.

Comment: Could you please add the input example that does not work to the fiddle?

Comment: Here is an example stack:

278.091182 spec35
279.300274 2
279.842670 3
280.204268 4
281.006563 5
281.503759 6
282.339954 7
282.532053 8
282.690252 9
283.300448 10
285.357034 11
285.718632 12
286.407927 e
287.809118 spec36
288.747012 2
288.927811 3
289.266809 4

Comment: Would it be possible to rephrase the question so it's more generally applicable to the community? I'm not sure I understand it well enough to edit it that way, but I think you want to parse two fields of input data such that when the second field is of a different value to the previous value, you want to change some other value. Perhaps use that as a starting point?

Comment: I'm not against someone rephrasing it but I'm not sure how it should be rephrased.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would not use a loop here, but a global regex with a [function for `replace`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter). It does match the full group (number plus spec, or number and integer) and replaces it with the number plus the spec. If a spec number was matched, it will update the `spec` variable and use that:

```
var str = '19.32    spec03 20.56    2 20.84 3';
var spec = "06"; // initial spec number
return str.replace(/(\d+\.\d+)\s+(spec)?(\d+)/g, function(whole, num, sp, spn) {
    if (sp) // second group matched "spec"
        spec = spn; // set new spec number
    return num + "\tspec" + spec;
});
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/wyE2x/4/))

Comment: This works perfectly. I'll need to study what you did here for some time. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I reworked your code completely, but this should do it:

```
var str = '19.32    spec03 20.56    2 20.84 3';
var items = str.split(/\s+/);   // break up at whitespace

var xyz = "spec06"; // spec number
items = items.map(function(item) {    // cycle through and modify each item
    if(item.indexOf("spec") != -1) {    
        xyz = item; // keep track of spec number
        return item;
    } else {
        return item+xyz;    // append spec number
    }
});
str = items.join("    ");    // join with whitespace again
```

Live version: http://jsfiddle.net/Tys95/

Comment: Thanks matt, is it possible to see a live version of what's going on here?